# Android Studio TFVC plugin : Commit fail after we delete file

Tags: android, android-studio, tfvc, android-studio-plugin

I have setup TFVC plugin in the android studio for subversion. My project is managed in TFVC.

I have deleted some file from my project and changed the package name. Then, I was trying to commit all to the server but every time it fails with an error message

**Files commit failed**

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you add more error logs?? if any?

Comment: That's the only error tag which i mentioned here.

Comment: try using tf status to get more helpful information, if the plugin is not giving you full disclosure just use the tfvc client directly

Comment: Can you please share any reference link for tfvc client which i can use independeny? Because i am not using visual studio.